# How strong is too strong for gravity wells and hyperspace?

Tags: star-wars, hyperspace

Maybe I'm just too critical as an astrophysicist, but I'm wondering if there's any official canon regarding how strong is too strong of a "gravity well" for safely jumping to hyperspace in Star Wars?

I think of the jumps to hyperspace I've seen in the movies and many of them occur  pretty close (at least what I would call close) to planets, where the gravity from the planet is still relatively strong.  It looks like many jumps to hyperspace occur at about the same distance above the planet as the distance of the planet's surface to the planet's center, where the force of gravity is a quarter of the value as at the planet's surface, smaller but not insignificant.

Even if you get far away from a planet before jumping to hyperspace, there's still the system's star's gravity well that you're in.

And even if you get far away from that star, you're still in the gravity well of every other massive object in the universe.  These gravity wells are weak since the objects are far away, but they are still there.

Thus my question: how strong is too strong for a gravity well to be unsafe to make a jump to hyperspace?

Comment: Don't forget that while there may be 10^29 times as much mass in the (observable! Very important for gravitational interaction) universe as in the Earth, most of that mass is 10^16 times further away or more. Apply the inverse-square law and you see the issue.

Comment: @Adamant, hence my statement in my post: "These gravity wells are weak since the objects are far away, but they are still there."

Comment: @Joshue - Tbh they're basically irrelevant. A star with a mass of 10^30 kg halfway across the galaxy (10^20 meters away) has less of an effect than a spaceship of 10^5 kg at a distance of a thousand kilometers. It's actually 99.9% weaker.

Comment: But, I guess you already know this, as an astrophysicist. I'm just pointing out that the gravity wells of distant stars are weaker than those of nearby spaceships and other common things in Star Wars.

Comment: @Adamant, indeed and thanks.  I bring up gravity wells of distant stars only to point out that there is nowhere in the universe that is completely free of a gravity well, no matter how weak.

Comment: To the close voters, this is still on topic. Specifically the first paragraph of the question makes it so.

Comment: @amflare That is good. I was just now thinking that it might be off topic when thinking back to other questions marked off topic. Going to do some research today!